# Is there a way to write a log on contents of a csv file

Tags: powershell, csv, logging

I'm very new to powershell. I am working exporting csv files from a database that gets updated periodically. For example, it will output csv files like  `Test1.csv` and the contents for the first run will be

`Test1.csv

 111,1,111
 222,1,222
 333,1,333`

if the script were to run the second time, the output of the same `Test1.csv` file will be

`Test1.csv

 111,1,111
 222,1,222`

is there a way to write a command to output to a log file that says, 333 has been removed from the Test1.csv file?

Comment: Use `Export-Csv` and PSCustomobjects

Comment: Full question is updated

Comment: As for 'is there a way to write a command to output to a log file that says, 333 has been removed', yes, you write your own logic for it at the time you do the remove, or you write that to a separate log file. You need to show your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar to the following:

```
$before = Get-Content Test1.csv

# Run some code here that may change Test1.csv

$after = Get-Content Test1.csv
$removed,$added = @(Compare-Object $before $after).where({$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='},'Split')
if ($removed) {
    "The following lines were removed: "
    $removed.InputObject
}
if ($added) {
    "The following lines were added: "
    $added.InputObject
}
```

**Explanation:**

You can read files with `Get-Content`. Typically, you would want to use `Import-Csv` with CSV files, but your files have no headers, the number of columns hasn't been guaranteed, and you don't want to manipulate the data.

`Compare-Object` by default will list differences in the two compared objects. The `SideIndicator` property of that output points to which object has the different data (a line of text in this case). Using `where()` method with the `Split` mode outputs objects that match the `{}` criteria in one array and the remaining objects in the other array. The data found to be different is stored in the `InputObject` property.